How to make gcloud CLI auth login fast as it is very slow?
I am using gcloud CLI with the gke-gcloud-auth-plugin. When running
the command gcloud auth login it takes several minutes before popping the
web browser page where I can authenticate.
After looking through the gcloud CLI Python code, I found the following workaround:
Adding the line 127.0.0.1 metadata.google.internal to the /etc/hosts file makes the auth
page pop immediately, making it possible to complete the auth flow successfully. However, the success page after authentication does time out with an error message, which is undesirable. I am running a VPN, but it does not seem to matter if the
VPN is active or not. I have no active proxy settings (but we will touch on this later).
How can I run the auth login command fast without an error at the end of the flow?
I found a related question. Given my current workaround it does not seem related.
Background to the workaround
The gcloud CLI is written in Python, which makes it possible to look through or debug the installed code.  While debugging, I found that when
the auth login command is executing, it checks if it is running in a GCE (Google Cloud Engine) environment.
It does this by TRYING to contact a host named metadata.google.internal. The associated code has timeouts and retry logic, which is probably the cause of my problem. The simple solution was to set that host to my localhost, which makes the retry logic
fail fast (the browser window pops instantly). While digging around in the code, I found the environment variable GCE_METADATA_ROOT (possibly renamed to GCE_METADATA_HOST) and the default/fallback value was metadata.google.internal.
Looking more into the code, I found the gcloud config settings gce_metadata_check_timeout_sec and gce_metadata_read_timeout_sec, under the 'compute' section,  but they are hidden=True and maybe the reason they do not show up in gcloud configuration page under the 'compute' section.
The code seems to explicitly call  gce_read.ReadNoProxy(...), therefore I am assuming that the OS proxy settings will not be used.
I wanted to mention the environment variable and property/configuration settings as they seem to indicate that there could be some more official way of doing what I want to do,
which is to inform the gcloud CLI that my computer is not a Google compute engine node in their cloud infrastructure: please stop trying to contact it for several minutes and avoid the timeout in the browser auth flow. The timeout happens sometimes not every time for some reason.
